# using Flyway for MongoDb in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, flyway

I use Flyway in Spring project that has 2 databases: mysql and mongodb. I want to keep order of migrations to both data sources and be able to move data from one to other one (use mysql+mongo in one migration).

Is it ok to use Flyway java-based-migrations for mongodb migrations?

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's completely fine to run MongoDB migrations as a flyway java migration, you only need to be sure that the migration is idempotent and prepare for possible failures, unlike SQL migrations Flyway won't perform a rollback if the transaction fails in the middle.

Another alternative would be [Mongobee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee), it's like Flyway but for MongoDB. But it also relies on java based migrations.

Comment: but sopposed to be with both Mongobee and Flyway sametime you cannot propperly execute migration in proper order. for example sql > mongo > sql. And it won't allow to use both sql and mongo in one migration

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you want to perform multiple sql and mongo migrations in a specific order then going for a full flyway approach will give you much better control.